# Hide or remove Qty box for bundle product in Magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

Spent some time trying to figure out how to hide the quantity box only for dropdown menu in bundle products. I just trying to hide the Qty boxes that appear under each product in bundle products, not the box next to "Add to cart" button. I see that it's slightly different from magento version but I use 1.9.1. If anyone could help me out would be much appreciated!

Comment: Solved it with <span class="qty-holder" style="display:none"> for bundle  in select.phtml

Comment: Just a quick note for anyone else with this issue: if you REMOVE the Qty boxes from the template, Magento will fail to calculate the 'price as configured' correctly. So this is most definitely the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think you can put condition for check product type before qty box

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$productType = $product->getTypeId();
if($productType != 'bundle'){
   <input type="text" name="qty" value="" >
}
```